# Why does my jQuery-script not work with Internet Explorer 7

Tags: jquery

As I've got errors in IE7 - I should to take a closer look at JS file - written before ...(by others).

at this point I'm not sure about anything, so I'd like to ask you - from my point of view is this wrong (aslo spacing can cause problems, I think) - but it is done all over the site:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready( function() {
          //the code
    });
})(jQuery);
```

oh and yes, the error in IE8:

> HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element
>   before the child element is closed (KB927917) - which make me think
>   the JS is in error.

I know that this is a silly question, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: ever tried to google? ever thought of an internet-explorer-problem?

Comment: The code in your question is fine. It's a closure which ensures the `$` is always reserved for jQuery within it. The error is coming from somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code posted that would cause this error.  Indeed, I don't see any code posted other than a closure around the `jQuery` object.  If that's causing an error by itself then there's something wrong with your jQuery download or with your browser.  Also, how would spacing cause problems?

Comment: hm ... so that's ok .. I've got warnings in jslint that there shouldn't be any space between '(' and 'function' thus I thought that this could cause problems in IE

Comment: @AngelM.: I'm not familiar with jslint, but that seems like nothing more than a stylistic concern to me.  The JavaScript interpreter isn't going to care if there's a space there or not.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair of course I've googled for this issue and I know what is the issue about - I just could not find where the mistakes in the code lies

Comment: @David thanks David, I'm not very familiar with it either - I just make a try and I have the same opinion as you - that is a stylistic concern

Comment: @AngelM.: To the question at hand... Where do this error come from?  Is there a specific line of code that throws this error?  What's happening when the error is thrown?

Comment: @David in IE7 I've got a warn - there is a problem and when I click OK, the page is not found. I checked this in IE8, and here this warn appears, so I tried to find out what is called before the child is called (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927917/en-us -here is explanation, but I don't have nothing similar in the code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always seen it like this. This will wait until the document is loaded before running any scripts.

```
$(function() {
  //the code
});
```

If you need to use another library that would cause collisions with the $ that jQuery uses, use this

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

[Have a look at the $.noConflict() documentation here.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: This would cause collisions if `$` is used by another framework or script, though.  The method used in the question wraps a closure around `$` and explicitly passes the `jQuery` object to it to prevent this.  In most cases it's not necessary, but it is generally safer.

Comment: @David I updated my answer based on your comment.